# Different scales (or resolutions) for different apps in the same screen?

Tags: macos, shortcut, screen, mojave, resolution

Today my cat stepped on my keyboard and somehow changed the scale of one app. The problem is that scale of the display is globally the same what changed was the overall resolution of my app.
[image: Different sizes]

[image: another example]
In the image above, there's the corner of chrome in the usual resolution, on the right is the corner for Discord, much much scaled.

I also added a photo of a widget within Chrome scaled.
Anyone knows how can I correct this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: ask your cat :)

Comment: hover the mouse pointer over the green circle in the small window. What does it shows ?

Comment: if you Hold the Option key and click on the Green circle it will show you a plus sign and scale the window up.

Comment: @Buscar웃 doesnt do anything, is just the buttom to size the window but it doesnt change the rwsolution.

Comment: @Buscar웃 this only adjust the window to the screen but it doesnt change the resolution :(

Comment: what resolution are you talking about ? I do not see it

Comment: @Buscar웃 the size of the screen in the right is not correct it should have the same dimensions but you can see that not even the buttoms are the same size, the right screen is super scaled somehow, the whole window looks like a different resolution.

Comment: after reading some stuff on the www, it sounds like Discord Canary might fix some of they screen stuff.

Comment: @Buscar웃 interestingly enough a few days ago he did it with a Chrome widget...

Comment: best course of action would be to video tape the cat :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 hahaha, he basically butt-hacked my config...

Comment: since the Discord is your top window, the Discord shortcuts are active, now which one does your scenario I do not know, but suggest you read about Discord hotkeys

Comment: I added the other case the case made an scale but in a widget of Chrome.

Comment: It’s called the Great Suspender.

Comment: try following Control+Shit+U to restore that window ... retracing cats steps

Comment: @Buscar웃 not yet... it doesnt do anything...

Comment: OK, lets summarize, the problem only occurs in Chrome, with some help from the cat.

Comment: @Buscar웃 no, is the Discord app, not the web based.

Comment: idk about the different sized apps - never seen anything like it - but content scaling within a browser ought to correct with Cmd/0 [cmd/+ or -  for finer granularity].

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85915/discussion-on-question-by-gary-j-espitia-s-different-scales-or-resolutions-f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Discord's User Settings you can change the "Zoom Level" of the whole window under "App Settings > Appearance".
<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> can also be used to change this Zoom level.

<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> is meant to set it back to default.

Comment: Same as Tetsujin already mentioned ;)

Comment: It would be nice to get an explanation for the downvote...

Comment: this one fixed it! Haha you made it. Hard to imagine that this command could change the resolution of the whole UI. I thought it only worked in Chrome. Thank you man, and everybody else for helping me son insistenly with this new problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly one app seems larger than another app?

Unfortunately it is not possible to adjust the resolution for an individual app. On macOS (and Windows too) the resolution of the screen is set on a screen by screen basis and can't be set for a specific app.

In System preferences > Displays

You can adjust those parameters.

If you have more than one display you could adjust the resolution on each display and keep those particular apps on the screen they look best on.

Comment: Unluckily it is possible... how otherwise could one explain the image I sent? Those are two different apps screens one next to the other...

Comment: The programmer(s) making a mistake? An older version? A bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar issue when dragging a window to a new desktop (Through the desktop thumbnails at the top of the screen).

While dragging the window up, there is a particular point as the window shrinks fit into the other desktop's thumbnail where you can let it go and the window simply stays on the current desktop but gets stuck at a smaller size.

This might possibly be the same issue (Though I'm not sure what your second screenshot is showing).

The only way I've found to undo it is to close the app and open it again.

It happens very occasionally for me, but I haven't been able to reproduce it purposefully.