# How can I resize the buttons of macOS?

Tags: macos

How can I resize the maximize and minimize the buttons of macOS? They are small, and I want to resize them. How can I set them?

[image]

Comment: permanently or temporary and why are you doing it

Comment: It might be possible using MacForge, but it'll be kinda a hassle.

Comment: You can change the scale of the whole display in the Displays pane in System Settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design of macOS cannot be modified easily — if at all.

For security reasons, the OS is on a signed read-only volume, and if it is modified, it might not boot.

Comment: Seems possible, if you are the developer of the app: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342987/different-scales-or-resolutions-for-different-apps-in-the-same-screen/343033#343033